# Function prototypes and enum

Tags: c++, enums, global, function-prototypes

I've declared a global enum type in my program and want various functions within my program to return instances of the enum type. Here is my declaration:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_
#include <SDL.h>
#include "LTexture.h"
#include "LButton.h"
#include "Initializationetc.h"

enum LButtonSprite
{
    BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_OUT = 0,
    BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_OVER_MOTION = 1,
    BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_DOWN = 2,
    BUTTON_SPRITE_TOTAL = 2
};
...
```

However, when I go try and build a function that returns "LButtonSprite" the following happens:

```
#ifndef LBUTTON_H
#define LBUTTON_H
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Global.h"

class LButton
{
public:
    //Initializes internal variables
    LButton();

    //Sets top left position
    void setPosition(int x, int y);

    //Handles mouse event
    void handleEvent(SDL_Event* e);

    //Shows button sprite
    void render();

    LButtonSprite getCurrSprite();//here

private:
    //Button Position
    SDL_Point mPosition;

    //Button Sprite
    LButtonSprite mCurrentSprite; //and here.

};
#endif
```

It seems as if the Visual Studio is mistaking the function prototype `LButtonSprite getCurrSprite();` for a declaration of a variable called getCurrSprite() of type LButtonSprite. The colour coding provided by VS (as seen above) seems to confirm this suspicion. Return types are blue, but LButtonSprite is light blue which is the colour reserved for variables.

The problem isn't just cosmetic unfortunately. I'm getting a bunch ofC4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int. I've added comments to the code at the lines where the error is occurring. The complete error log is included at the end of the post.

How can I correct this mistake?

Error log:

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 22  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 29  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 22  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   11  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 29  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   14  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\global.h  34  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   17  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 22  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   20  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 29  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mCurrentSprite'  c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 29  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   10  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mCurrentSprite'  c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 29  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   19  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mCurrentSprite'  c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 29  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getCurrSprite'   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 22  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getCurrSprite'   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 22  1   SDL2_tutorials
Error   16  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getCurrSprite'   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl2_tutorials\sdl2_tutorials\lbutton.h 22  1   SDL2_tutorials

Comment: Do you actually get an error when compiling? Or are you just wanting a different colour on screen? (From what I can see, the code looks good)

Comment: What does the compiler say? Only possible error can be that `class LButton` is defined before `enum LButtonSprite` (the former being included in `LButton.h`). What are names of the header files?

Comment: Are you saying the code does not work as expected or are you saying the IDE is coloring it in a way that is not consistent with the way you think it should appear?  Is the code broken or the IDE not behaving as you expect it to?

Comment: @MatsPetersson error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: correct c compiler would never mistake identifier() as variable because of brackets, they always make it a function! :)

Comment: Minor nitpick, but relevant - where's the #endif for the #ifndef protection in the "Global.h" file?

Comment: The problem could be with the mutual header inclusion. Global and LButton are including each other, which causes problems in certain circumstances. Why don't you move the enum declaration to the LButton header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Return types are blue

No – *keywords* are blue. Why else would `enum`, `class`, `public` and `private` be blue? Return types have no special syntax highlighting. The problem in your code is completely unrelated:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_
#include <SDL.h>
#include "LTexture.h"
#include "LButton.h"
```

The last line includes (and thus declares) the `LButton` class, *before* you define your `enum`. Remove that line from the file, or define the enum before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you use VS2012. In VS2012, all user defined types(return values are no exception) are colored light blue. Dark blue are reserved words.

The reason why your function's return type is light blue is because the return type is a user defined type.

Comment: That’s not an answer though.

Comment: How so? I explained why the return type is colored light blue.

Comment: But that’s not actually OP’s problem. His problem is that the code doesn’t work.

Comment: Hmmm, only recently he commented that there is an error. He seemed to  be confused about the color coding earlier.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see you have `#include "LButton.h"` probably containing the definition of `class LButton` before declaration of the `enum LButtonSprite`, therefore the IDE and the compiler does not see the `LButtonSprite` declared in the `LButton`, hence the wrong coloring.

You should include it the other way around, `LButtonSprite.h` into `LButton.h`